# regex using positive lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

My source data text looks something like this:

```
a1,a2,a3
a4,a5,a6
a7,a8,a9
test="1"
b1,b2,b3
b4,b5,b6
b7,b8,b9
test="2"
c1,c2,c3
c4,c5,c6
c7,c8,c9
test="3"
```

I need to parse this so the end result looks like this (appropriate “test” field included in each row):

```
a1,a2,a3,1
a4,a5,a6,1
a7,a8,a9,1
b1,b2,b3,2
b4,b5,b6,2
b7,b8,b9,2
c1,c2,c3,3
c4,c5,c6,3
c7,c8,c9,3
...etc
```

this what I started with and captures the fields correctly:

```
(?<f1>.*?),(?<f2>.*?),(?<f3>.*?)\s+
```

I understand I need to use lookarounds to capture and include the “test” field on each line.

So something like this added (using a positive lookahead)…

```
(?<f1>.*?),(?<f2>.*?),(?<f3>.*?)\s+(?=test="(?<test>.*?)")
```

This seems close but is not yielding all rows of data, but instead only the last row of data with the included test value as if it is consuming the look ahead row.

This expression with its captured groups are input into a .NET application that inserts these captured groups as fields within a database table. Number of fields is always static (4 in the example above; field1=f1, field2=f2, field3=f3, field4=test), but the number of records will be variable.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What I failed to convey; the data above is only a snippet and is continuous for unknown and variable number of lines. As well as, I do need to use capture groups to capture each individual field. This is being used as input in to an app that will parse the data and insert into database fields.

Comment: What language are you using, can you edit the question to make it more specific? ie what's defining a field (a row, a `a1`...), if the number of lines is variable what about the number of comma delimited values, etc.

Comment: the app that accepts my regex is .NET. a1 is a field, a2 another field, a3 another field, and the final field is the test= value. each row would have 4 fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parsing your data to extract the relevant values**

You are almost there, but need to allow the look ahead to skip the rows between the current one and the test line:

```
(?ms)(?<f1>\w+),(?<f2>\w+),(?<f3>\w+)\R(?=.*?^test="(?<test>\d+)")
```

`\R` matches all sort of newlines, `(?ms)` is the inline way of turning on the multiline and dot match all modifiers, so that `.*?^test` matches every line up to the test one, see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/gS6mW2/2).

Again, your issue was that `\s+` forced the lookahead to be on the line right after the one your were matching.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to clarify and added a comment above. Based on this new information that I should have provided earlier, not sure your solution would work for me.

Comment: @user916077: edited my answer. As a side note if you want to add information to your question you should always edit it, not just comment on it (comments are only designed to convey a small amount of info).

Comment: that's it exactly, thank you. I did get an error with the \R so I used \n and that seemed to work and provide the results I needed.